# visual studio command line arguments username

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

How do I get the current user and pass it as a command line argument in VS.

I want to pass a path to my program  as follows "C:\Users\\" in the debug start options in my project.

[image]

Comment: Want u start application with command line?

Comment: no just pass in the location of a flie as an argument

Comment: I gave an answer but just noticed that you are starting Excel also, are you trying to pass the arguments directly to excel?